# GET request succesfully returning data but undefined when assigning to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a GET request which successfully returns the correct response data from the server, but when assigning the response to a variable called 'reportId' it becomes undefined.

The controller:

```
            if (resp.HasData)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dataRow in resp.AllData[0].Rows)
                {
                    ReportsModel rm = new ReportsModel();
                    rm.URL = dataRow["URL"].ToString();
                    reportsModelList.Add(rm);
                }
            }

            return Ok(reportsModelList);
```

Javascript:

```
        function showReport(reportName) {
            const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_a');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ReportsApi/generateReport/" + reportName,
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                        const reportId = data.URL;
                        console.log(reportId);

                        iframe.src = `${reportId}&autoAuth=true&pageNavigation=true`;
                    } else {
                        console.error('Error: No data returned from server');
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.error('Error updating data:', error);
                }
            });
        }
```

The `reportId` variable needs to receive the value from the `URL` property of the first object in the response data.

Comment: can I have what data you got on successful ajax call ?

Comment: @SaidurRahman the data received is simply a URL stored in an Array :

url: "https://app.powerbi.com/"

Comment: If `data` is an array you need to retrieve its elements via an index. e.g: `data[0].url`